# Pursuant to English grammar rules, what is destined in 1 Peter 2:8b, the stumble or the disobedience?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I am seeking an English grammatical analysis of 1 Peter 2:8b, as rendered in Net English Translation, in order to determine [what] is destined;i.e., the stumble or the disobedience.

I am not asking for a theological exegetical or hermeneutical analysis or any kind of interpretation of the text.

NET I Peter 2:7,8

> 7 So you who believe see his value, but for those who do not believe,
>   the stone that the builders rejected has become the cornerstone,
>
> 8 and a stumbling-stone and a rock to trip over. They stumble because
>   they disobey the word, as they were destined to do.

.

Comment: The logical interpretation of "do" must surely be "disobey the word".

Comment: @Nigel The quality of the translation was not the primary inquiry.

Comment: @BillJ could you expound further and submit as an answer?

Comment: @Nigel In spite of how bad it is, what is it saying when analyzed with English grammar?

Comment: @Nigel J 'Well, I know what Peter wrote; of that, there is no doubt.' would imply that you have access to the original manuscripts.

Comment: At the very least, this translation is ambiguous, and the default reading (at least nowadays) would be 'they were predestined to disobey'. This flies in the face of many other Scriptures where God says 'Obey, live righteously, and I will bless you' and even 'Confess your wrongdoings and I will cleanse you' and 'I desire all men to be saved' (i Tim 2:4) (paraphrasing).

Comment: "They" = "those who do not believe" = "[those who] were destined to [disobey the word]". It would be unduly reflexive to insist on the reading "they stumble because ... they were destined to stumble," which in any case would render the clause "because they disobey the word" irrelevant to the chain of causation.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Yes, it's definitely ambiguous; but can we resolve the ambiguity by applying English grammar rules apart from theological bias? I'm not asking for theological interpretation.

Comment: Why are you asking people to defend poor phraseology? Use a better translation.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - I'm asking for a grammatical analysis of the text. No express or implied defense is indicated anywhere is the OP or in my other comments. You may simply ignore the question.

Comment: @BillJ has said that the reading must be taken as 'They stumble because they disobey (as they were destined to do) the word'. That's using modern requirements. I'm aware of the possibility of the reading 'They stumble because they disobey the word – stumbling is an unavoidable consequence', if one allows more old-fashioned structuring. But when you're left guessing between two available sets of rules of grammar, 'Which is grammatical?' becomes a question better avoided. Find a version which makes things clear. (Of course, accuracy of translation is also crucial: which version gets it right?)

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth What are the two available sets of grammar?

Comment: I described them first. The modern requirement (probably still only a rule of thumb rather than a fully binding law) is that the nearer clause (here, 'they disobey the word') is the referent where this makes any sense at all. I've come across examples (usually in works over 100 years old) where this 'rule' isn't adhered to.

Comment: I would be interested to give an answer to this question but I would be using the Received Text and I would be quoting the interlinear translation of the Englishman's Greek New Testament in order to show what Peter actually meant.

Comment: @NigelJ Using a variation of the Received Text would not be directly relevant to the OP; however, it would be relevant here: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/30376/according-to-1-peter-27-8-unto-what-were-the-disobedient-destined

Comment: No one seems to have mentioned that if you interpret this as: "destined to do" as referring to disobeying the word, that would be somewhat under the purview of predestination; whereas if it goes with stumble, that is more "ur-Christian" since all Christians believe that they sin at some point or another in life. And that's how grammar does end up as  hermeneutics.

Comment: Pursuant to English grammar rules, it's ambiguous.  The modern rule of thumb is that the nearer clause is the referent, but this "rule" is often broken.  Usually, the violation of the rule is evident from the context and the nature of the clauses, but such evidence can get lost in linguistic history fairly easily, as meanings change over time and various idioms come and go.  So the only way to be reasonably confident as to what is meant is to review the source documents.

Comment: "I am not asking for an exegetical or hermeneutical analysis or any kind of interpretation of the text." Then you can't ask for a grammatical analysis, because that ***is*** exegetical analysis.

Comment: @curiousdanni That's a fair critique. I should have said I'm not asking for a theological exegesis; which would introduce information into the analysis beyond the scope of the OP.  I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want an hermeneutical analysis or similar interpretation of the text, then better get rid of it; and stick to the one sentence you are asking about. And/or come up with a parallel one. I do both here.

> They stumble because they disobey the word, as they were destined to do.

*As they were destined to do* is an adverbial clause (see [Grammar Monster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/adverbial_clauses.htm) and [Thought.com](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-adverbial-clause-1689190))

Note

> As a writer you often have to explain to your reader where things happened, why things happened, when they happened, or how they happened. As you have seen, to answer such questions requires the use of adverbs, whether you use an adverb, an adverbial phrase, or an *adverbial clause*. (See [Appositive Phrases, and Adverbial and Adjectival Phrases and Clauses](https://www.texasgateway.org/resource/appositive-phrases-and-adverbial-and-adjectival-phrases-and-clauses), italics mine.)

Regarding  the structure of your sentence,  the adverbial clause can apply either to the closest preceding  dependent clause, *disobey the word* or to to the complete   independent clause preceding the adverbial. Thus, in the second option,   they were destined to *stumble because they disobey the word*.

Compare the more pedestrian:

> They fell off their bike because they got a flat tire, as I predicted they would (do).

*As I predicted they would (do)* is an adverbial clause.

I predicted either  that they would 
 *get a flat tire*,  or they would *fall off their bike because they get a flat tire*.

So, a grammatical analysis does not provide a conclusive reading of the sentence.

Comment: I have always asked for a grammatical analysis of the text so I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "If you don't want an analysis".  Notwithstanding, please clarify if it is your conclusion that the answer is indecisive since grammatical rules permit both.

Comment: @InfinitelyManic - I personally think grammatical rules permit both.

Comment: So, is the conclusion that the NET translation results in there being no conclusion ? Or have I misunderstood ?

Comment: @NigelJ - No conclusion or an equivocation seems to be the current reasonable analysis.

Answer (score -1):

> They stumble because they disobey the word, as they were destined to do.

Assuming correct punctuation as in the original English translation, the semantic interpretation is simple and straightforward *unless one chooses to complicate it.☆*

For all the good grammatical reasons already covered by earlier answers, 'destined' here definitely applies to 'disobey' but it **can** -- it might or might not -- apply to 'stumble' as well, which means that from a strictly grammatical perspective both readings are possible:

> they were destined to *'disobey the written word'*, and stumbled as a consequence.
>
> they were destined to *'stumble because they disobeyed the written word.'*

However, most native speakers of English are likely to agree that the first reading was intended: 'destined' probably applies to 'disobey' alone. It is a matter to do with the logic of syntax, and stretching the meaning of 'destined' to apply to 'stumble' as well is a *logical overextension* for which no real justification seems to exist in either text or context.

I would suggest that if 'destined' really applied to 'stumble' then the translator would have used 'and' instead of 'as' to connect the two parts of the sentence:

> They stumble because they disobey the word, **and** they were destined to do (*so*).

▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪

☆[Occam's razor](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) : "it is never useful to make more assumptions than are absolute necessary to prove the case" (paraphrase.) Keep it simple. 'Destined' applies to 'disobey' alone.

Comment: Your statements appear to conflict; i.e., "from a strictly grammatical perspective both readings are possible:" vs "'Destined' applies to 'disobey' only".

Comment: Both readings are grammatically possible but there is no need to read the bible from a strictly grammatical perspective @InfinitelyManic. You could take a poll of native speakers from diverse backgrounds and 9 out of 10 would tell you that from a common-sense perspective, 'destined' applies to 'disobey' only, but that type of poll is off-topic here on English.StackExchange.

Comment: Generally, most native speaks cannot recall all of the grammatical rules that may have been learned many years ago. I certainly can't. So that's why I'm seeking out answers from those that still have a firm grip on the rules. I'm primarily interested in a grammatical analysis of the text knowing that such analysis may not rise to a "proper" interpretation of the text.  I'm looking for a judgment of the text strictly through the lens of English grammar.

Comment: It is fine as an exercise in syntax and grammar and I appreciate your interest,  but I do think there is the risk of misinterpretation, overinterpretation and even multiple parallel interpretations of the text by considering **all grammatically possible** meanings -- note too I am not a native speaker of English myself @InfinitelyManic.

Comment: - The entire purpose of the OP is to seek a fine exercise in English grammar in respect to the subject text. The risk of interpretation of the text is immaterial in the instant case since it can be objectively ignored.

Comment: I took some time to understand your real purpose @InfinitelyManic. That makes it an unusual and very interesting exercise. I suppose you got your specific answer as given by at least 2 posts: *a grammatical analysis does not provide a conclusive reading of the sentence //  from a strictly grammatical perspective both readings are possible.*

Answer (score -3):

The inclusion of a comma effectively decouples the second and final clauses, so we must look for an earlier clause that the final clause must refer to. So, they were destined to stumble.

If we had:

> They stumble because they disobey the word as they were destined to do.

then we can infer that they were destined to disobey.

Comment: But, they were destined to disobey--that's what the text is trying to say, even if they got the punctuation wrong.  I wonder what the original Greek would tell us.

Comment: @Xanne I agree that the translation may be suspect, but that was not what the quaerant wanted to know. Perhaps someone can provide a clearer example (and explanation) of the grammatical rule.

Comment: I see your point, but I'm not sure the comma "effectively decouples" those clauses.  I don't think you can make a case for that; it is an unreferenced claim.

Comment: I look forward to reading a more learned opinion (and the OP was, perhaps, a little rash in accepting my answer). I just thought I would take a punt at the question.

Comment: @Xanne I agree that the comma does not necessarily decouple the two clauses. Nor do I know why such decoupling would result in reference to the subordinate clause rather than the main clause. Moreover, this is poetry meant to be read aloud. Are we to distinguish between a "stumbling stone" and a  "rock to trip over"? The disobeying  is being equated with stumbling. Did the Holy Ghost whisper where to place commas into the ear of Saint Jerome?

Comment: I'm no Biblical scholar, but surely "do" is interpreted as "disobey the word".

Comment: @Jeff Morrow We're not sure about the whispering.  But, we're not distinguishing between a rock and a stumbling stone.  We're saying that the intended meaning is that they were destined to disobey.

Comment: It would be useful if someone could formulate an equally ambiguous, but equivalent sentence, without the theological baggage, so that we can analyse it.

Comment: @Mick I will deselect the answer and I was perhaps a bit rash.

Comment: @Xanne - I'm only interested in an English grammatical analysis of the text not for the the truth of the matter asserted, to use a legal term. The underlying original language is only relative to the extent I want to know if it's a good translation.

Comment: @InfinitelyManic Yes, I understand that.

Comment: @Xanne '_I wonder what the original Greek would tell us ?_' : γμιν ουν η τιμη τοις πιστευοσιν απειθουσιν δε λιθον ον απεδοκιμασαν οι οικοδομουντες ουτος εγενηθη εις κεφαλην γωνιας και λιθος προσκομματος και πετρα σκανδαλου οι προσκοπτουσιν τω λογω απειθουντες εις ο και ετεθησαν.

Comment: I was reading your answer and a minute later it disappeared without a trace. Was it deleted (and if so, why) @Nigel J?

Comment: @EnglishStudent Comments are not permanent. They can be deleted, either by the system or by moderators.

Comment: Yes indeed @Mick but this was an actual *answer* by Nigel J with elements of *both* grammar and hermeneutics, which vanished without a trace between my first and second reading! Maybe the author deleted it temporarily pending further editing.

Comment: @EnglishStudent My answer, as you say, dealt with the underlying issues of Textual Criticsm, translation from the Greek language and hermeneutic translation as well as the grammar of the quoted translation. But much of that is off topic here, so I decided, on second thoughts, to delete.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @Nigel J. It's a good and comprehensive answer in context. **As long as you do address the grammatical aspect independently in sufficient detail**, I think it can stand as on-topic here and all the other elements you covered will give it depth and scope. So what if somebody downvotes? Somebody who appreciates it will upvote later. Too good an answer to be left in the freezer, I think.